# How to Modify Login Block to make 'Create New User Account' link redirect to page other than user/register in Drupal 6.x

Tags: drupal-theming

I would like to have my (Create New Account) redirect to a page other than registration page. I found a workaround in which one inserts a simple code into the template.php file. This works very well if the theme is Garland or alike. The problem with me is: I am using Ad-novus theme in which I could not find the template.php file where I should have inserted the solver code. Can anyone please help with this by telling me whether there is an alternative file that I can use instead of the template.php. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a template.php file and paste that simple code. That's all :-)

Drupal theme engine system will load that file automatically and load your code snippet. And remember to flush cache if it don't work [1]

[1] /admin/settings/performance